# Custom Grid App

Tags: rally

So I am trying to make modifications to the custom grid app that rally has already created.  I found the source code at https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/grid.  However, I cannot get that code to work.  I have added it to a js and then ran build (I also changed the json).  However, when I then add the app to rally it doesn't give me the settings options (object, query, pagesize, etc) and just generates a table.  This table generates 4 rows (the number of user stories I have), but the rows are completely blank except for gears at the beginning of each row.  I was wondering if I was building this app incorrectly or if I had grabbed the wrong code.  If not, is there a place where can I get the complete code or a way to modify the already existing code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may add a `fetch` to the config as below:

```
 config: {
            defaultSettings: {
                types: 'hierarchicalrequirement',
                fetch: 'FormattedID,Name'
            }
        }
```

and it will display a grid.

It will not display settings dialog however. The source code in this [github repo](https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/grid) is not exactly the [CustomGrid](https://help.rallydev.com/custom-grid) app available from the AppCatalog in the UI. It does not have the full functionality and not ready yet. I submitted a defect.